# select2 dropdown value stored locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have multiple select2 drop-downs. Their value are loaded from their respective json files. The form is slow to load.

1. I want to combine their json files into one file. How do I change my javascript to read from one json file?
2. Is it possible to save drop-down values locally, so when the form is loaded the second time, it reads from the memory not read json files again.

```js
function mySelect2(file,field) {
    $.getJSON(file, function(obj) {
        $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
            $(field).select2({
                data: [
                    {
                        id: value,
                        text: key
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
    });
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            mySelect2("../data/contactsourcesources.json",'#source_of_contact');
            mySelect2("../data/levelofstudysources.json",'#degree');
            //mySelect2("../data/institutionssources.json",'#uni');
            //mySelect2("../data/countries.json",'#countryorigin');
            mySelect2("../data/degreessources.json",'#course');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body >
       <section>
             <label for="source_of_contact">
              Contact Method:
             <select class="source_of_contact" id="source_of_contact" name="source_of_contact">
             </select>
             </label>
             
             <label for="degree" class="lbl-text">Degree Type:<span id="required">*</span>
             <select class="degree" id="degree" name="degree">
             </select>
             </label>
       </section>
</body>
</html>
```

**Json file:**

```
{"Caf\u00e9 Connect\n":"7e0a7146","Academic Advising Day\n":"academic_advising_day"}
```

I want to change the **Json** and **JavaScript** to

```
{"source_of_contact":{"Caf\u00e9 Connect\n":"7e0a7146","Academic Advising Day\n":"academic_advising_day"}}

function mySelect2(file,field) {
$.getJSON(file, function(obj) {
    // obj.field, how do I get value of field? I want to be like this
    // obj.source_of_contact
    $.each(obj.field, function(key, value) {
        $(field).select2({
            data: [
                {
                    id: value,
                    text: key
                }
            ]
        });
    });
});}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, do you need the file path to have multiple way, and to store data,, assign it to gobal variable. the question is bit un clear.

Comment: I will rewrite my question.

Comment: I want to read dropdown values from one json file not multiple json files.

Comment: Also I want my form load faster.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is exactly you want?

Comment: How do I get `mySelect2(file,field)` to read from a json file that looks like this `{"source_of_contact":{"Caf\u00e9 Connect\n":"7e0a7146"`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use CDN, download and use the local copy of the js . That will increase the time a bit,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

second in order to make it load the data faster don't call the all GetJSOn function at document ready, call each function one after another on change of the dropdown values.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of calling mySelect2 on change of dropdown values.

Comment: $('#idOfSelect').hide() // hiding it on document ready
$('#idOfSelect1').on('change',function(){  $.getJSON(file, function(obj) { //bind the value to select2 dropdown} ; $('#idOfSelect').show() })

Comment: @VinodkumarG If you use CDN then it will cache in browser memory & from next time it will load from cache, so using CDN is better that local copy of script

Comment: @Shiladitya Yes, you are correct, but based on meta data tags present in html can restrict cache option.